# ffmpeg image scrolling with background image

Tags: image, video, scroll, ffmpeg

I have code

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 24 -i "image.jpg" -filter_complex "color=000000:s=640x360[bg];[bg][0]overlay=shortest=1:y='min(0,-(t)*26)'" -qscale 1 -y out.mpg
```

How to change this code so that instead of a black base color there was a background in the form of an image?

I will be grateful for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another image input and use it as the background in the overlay:

```
ffmpeg -y -i background.jpg -loop 1 -t 24 -i "image.jpg" -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=y='min(0,-(t)*26)'" -qscale 1 out.mpg
```

Comment: Thank you! Best wishes to you!